# When using MVC 5 Razor with VB, why is the '@' required in front of basic html tags?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

This code will not work without the @ in front of the 'li' tag.

```
@For Each A In ViewBag.stuff  (where stuff is a list of strings)
  @<li>@A</li>
Next
```

Is there an easy rule to remember to know when the @ is required to transition back to html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is required when the previous line is plain code (such as `For Each`).

This is because in VB there are [XML literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx) that create ambiguity.